# Reverse Words at odd position only C#

Tags: c#, string

This is my code. How can I edit it to show every word which is at the *odd position ONLY* to be reversed?

```
        for (int i = input.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (input[i] == ' ')
            {
                result =  tmp + " " + result;
                tmp = "";
            }
            else
                tmp += input[i];
        }

        result = tmp + " " + result;
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Example input:

> "How **are** you **today**"

to output:

> "How **era** you **yadot**"

Based on the *position of a word* ['How' -> 0] do not reverse; [are -> 1 odd index] Reverse

Comment: take the words, loop through and only change the odd ones..

Comment: Could you provide some examples of input and the desired outcome?

Comment: *Define* odd words. Is "odd" based on the *position within a sentence*, or the *length of the individual word*, something else numerical or something else entirely? Don't expect *us* to be able to know what *you* mean here.

Comment: OP Tag me in a comment here if you post an updated version of this question. Assuming it's odd based on position, I was working on an answer before it was closed.

Comment: I was about to post the answer! Ugh. OP: as far as I understood, you can check this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IWnTSo  cheers! :)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever here I have updated it. Sorry this is my first time using stackoverflow to ask a question and I'm pretty new at it

Comment: @john I've updated it. Sorry I am new to this website and I hope I will learn to ask the right questions

Comment: @Laken-C your sample I/O does not make much sense, `How` is odd in length and so is `you`. Please try being more crystal.

Comment: What is the expected outcome for `"I want to reverse all odd words (odd words only!)."` string?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko odd positioned words must be reversed in a sentence. Example: Hello World must outcome: "Hello dlroW"

Comment: As a sidenote, while index 1 is odd, the *position* of an element at index 1 is even, because it is the *second* element in the array.

Comment: What have you tried yourself in regards to the reversing of certain words?

Comment: This question should be re-opened!

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve it with the help of LINQ:

```
var input = "hello this is a test message";
var inputWords = input.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var result = string.Join(" ", 
                 inputWords.Select((w, i) => 
                                         i % 2 == 0
                                         ? w 
                                         : new string(w.Reverse().ToArray())
                 ));
```

Where `w` in the select is the word, and `i` is the index, starting at 0 for the first word. `%` is the modulus operator and gets the remainder. If `i % 2 == 0` (i.e. i can be divided by 2 with no remainder), then the original is returned. If there is a remainder (odd) then the reversed word is returned. Finally, it's all wrapped up in a `string.Join(" ", items);` which turns it back into a normal string rather than an array of items.

[Try it online](http://rextester.com/NVKGU63996)

Comment: `input.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` is a safier option in case a *double space* appears

Comment: @Dmitry That's true. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

So far you have a `string`, like this:

```
  string input = "I want to reverse all odd words (odd words only!).";
```

And you, naturally, want to perform the task. Now it's the main question what's an **odd** word?
If you mean *word's position* (`I` at position `0`, `want` at `1` - *should be reversed* etc.) 
then you can use *regular expressions* to match words and *Linq* to process them:

```
  using System.Linq;                     // To reverse single word
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;  // To match the words within the text

  ... 

  // Let's elaborate the test example: add
  //  1. some punctuation - ()!. - to preserve it 
  //  2. different white spaces (spaces and tabulation - \t)
  //     to add difficulties for naive algorithms
  //  3. double spaces (after "to") to mislead split based algorithms
  string input = "I want to  reverse all\todd words (odd words only!).";

  int index = 0;                                // words' indexes start from zero

  string result = Regex.Replace(
    input,
   "[A-Za-z']+",                                // word is letters and apostrophes
    match => index++ % 2 == 0 
      ? match.Value                             // Even words intact
      : string.Concat(match.Value.Reverse()));  // Odd words reversed

  Console.WriteLine(result);
```

If you want to reverse the words with odd `Length`, i.e. `I`, `all`, `odd` then all you have to do is to change the condition to

```
    match => match.Value % 2 == 0
```

Outcome:

```
  I tnaw to  esrever all    ddo words (ddo words ylno!).
```

Please, notice, that the *punctuation* has been *preserved* (only *words* are reversed).

Answer (score 3):

*OP: Based on the position of a word ['How' -> 0] do not reverse; [are -> 1 odd index] Reverse*

```
public static void Main()
{
    string input = "How are you today Laken-C";

     //As pointed out by @Dmitry Bychenko string input = "How are you today";
    //(double space after How) leads to How are uoy today outcome 

    input = Regex.Replace(input, @"\s+", " ");
    var inp = input.Split(' ').ToList();

    for (int j = 0; j < inp.Count(); j++)
    {   
       if(j % 2 == 1)
       {
           Console.Write(inp[j].Reverse().ToArray());
           Console.Write(" ");
       }
       else
           Console.Write(inp[j] + " ");
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

DEMO:

[dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MbkCZr)

Comment: `string input = "How  are you today";` (*double space* after `How`) leads to `How  are uoy today` outcome

Comment: @DmitryBychenko fixed

Answer (score 0):

try this is perfect working code..

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string orgstr = "my name is sagar";
        string revstr = "";
        foreach (var word in orgstr.Split(' '))
        {
            string temp = "";
            foreach (var ch in word.ToCharArray())
            {
                temp = ch + temp;
            }
            revstr = revstr + temp + " ";
        }

        Console.Write(revstr);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Output: **ym eman si ragas**